# Mysql Check integer availability

Tags: mysql, gaps-and-islands

I would like to know if there is a possibility to create a query that returns the smallest integer available. It's a bit complicated to explain, but with an example it facilitates:

Code: 1 2 4 5 6

In this case, I would like the query to return the number 3, since it is the smallest integer that is still available.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

I have the followings tables:

```
Itens
+----+-----------+------+
| id | name      | code |
+----+-----------+------+
| 1  | produto 1 | 1    |
+----+-----------+------+
| 2  | produto 2 | 2    |
+----+-----------+------+
| 3  | produto 3 | 4    |
+----+-----------+------+
| 4  | produto 4 | 6    |
+----+-----------+------+

Categories
+----+------------+------------+
| id | name       | company_id |
+----+------------+------------+
| 1  | Category 1 |     1      |
+----+------------+------------+
| 2  | Category 2 |     2      |
+----+------------+------------+

Companies
+----+-----------+
| id | name      |
+----+-----------+
| 1  | Company 1 |
+----+-----------+
| 2  | Company 2 |
+----+-----------+
```

I need do it for each company int the trigger. I try the code bellow, but doesn't work.

```
CREATE TRIGGER `updateCodigoNull`
BEFORE INSERT ON `itens`
FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    IF (NEW.codigo IS NULL)
    THEN
      SET NEW.codigo = (SELECT b.codigo - 1
                        FROM (
                               (SELECT
                                  2 AS 'codigo',
                                  1 AS 'missing',
                                  1 AS 'previous'
                                FROM itens
                                  INNER JOIN item_categories ON itens.category_id = item_categories.id
                                WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1
                                                 FROM itens
                                                 WHERE codigo = 1) AND item_categories.company_id = 2
                                LIMIT 1)
                               UNION
                               (SELECT
                                  codigo,
                                  IF(@previous != 0 AND @previous < codigo - 1, 1, 0) AS missing,
                                  @previous := codigo
                                FROM itens
                                  INNER JOIN item_categories
                                    ON itens.category_id = item_categories.id
                                  , (SELECT @previous := 0) a
                                WHERE item_categories.company_id = 2
                               )) b
                        WHERE b.missing = 1
                        ORDER BY b.codigo
                        LIMIT 1);
    END IF;
  END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the following technique:

```
SELECT i1.codigo + 1 AS unused_codigo
FROM itens AS i1
LEFT OUTER JOIN itens AS i2
  ON i1.codigo + 1 = i2.codigo
WHERE i2.codigo IS NULL
```

This works because the outer join will return NULL where there's no match, that is when there is no code for i1.codigo + 1. This works for any gap, and also for the last value in the table.

It's a little more complicated. We want to also find if the code 1 is missing, so we need to make the i1 table unioned with the literal value 0.

Also you seem to have a requirement that the search be limited to categories associated with company 2 (though this is not clear from your description, it's in your example query).

```
SELECT i1.codigo + 1 AS unused_codigo
FROM (
  SELECT 0 AS codigo
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT i.codigo 
  FROM itens AS i 
  JOIN item_categories AS c1 
    ON i.category_id = c1.id AND c1.company_id = 2
) AS i1
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
  itens AS i2 
  JOIN item_categories AS c2 
    ON i2.category_id = c2.id AND c2.company_id = 2
) ON i1.codigo + 1 = i2.codigo
WHERE i2.codigo IS NULL
ORDER BY unused_codigo
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! Worked perfectly! Just change t1 by i1 and t2 by i2 (:

Comment: Thanks, I have fixed that.

Answer (score 1):

If these numbers are row ids then you can use query variables to keep track of precvious ids and return the first id when the difference is more than 1, e.g.:

**Create and Insert scripts:**

```
create table test(id int);
insert into test values(1);
insert into test values(2);
insert into test values(4);
insert into test values(5);
insert into test values(7);
```

**Query:**

```
SELECT b.id - 1
FROM (
    SELECT id, IF(@previous != 0 AND @previous < id - 1, 1, 0) as missing, @previous:= id 
    FROM test , (SELECT @previous := 0) a
    ORDER BY id
    ) b
WHERE b.missing = 1
LIMIT 1;
```

This will return `3`. If you want first 2 missing ids then you can change the `LIMIT` to `2` and it will return both `3` and `6`.

**Update**

If you want the query to return values like `1` if they do not exist then you can add another query and `UNION` the result, e.g.:

```
SELECT b.id - 1
FROM (
  SELECT 2 AS 'id', 1 AS 'missing', 1 AS 'previous' FROM test WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM test WHERE id = 1) LIMIT 1
  UNION 
  SELECT id, IF(@previous != 0 AND @previous < id - 1, 1, 0) as missing, @previous:= id 
  FROM test , (SELECT @previous := 0) a
  ) b
WHERE b.missing = 1
ORDER BY b.id
LIMIT 1;
```

Above would return 1, here's the **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9367b/5/0)**.

Comment: If I have the ids: 4,5,6,7 and 8, I would like the result to be 1. Is it possible to adapt?

Comment: @Cristian as this query works out the missing id by looking into existing entries, it won't return 1, it will always start from the min(id).

Comment: Is it possible return the id 1 when it does not exist?

Comment: @Cristian yes, I have updated the answer with another example.

Comment: Thank you very much! Worked perfectly. But I have a problem, I'm creating a trigger with this code, I have updated the post with the example

Comment: @Cristian that might be because of `NEW.codigo` in trigger. It should be `NEW.code` as `codigo` column does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

This query will JOIN to your table and  get the minimum missing id,the subqbery generates 1000 integers it can easily be expanded for more.

```
select MIN(a.numbs) 
from (
    select 1000 -  (a.a + (10 * b.a) + (100 * c.a))  as numbs
    from (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as a
    cross join (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as b
    cross join (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as c
) a LEFT JOIN t
ON a.numbs =t.id
WHERE t.id IS NULL
```

[See it working](http://rextester.com/GVCGRF47803)